# Checking TLS 1.2 enabled or not on my Windows Server

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2019, windows-registry

I need to check if TLS 1.2 is enabled on my Windows Server 2019.

In the registry the key **TLS 1.2** is not present under Protocols

[image]

But when I browse on a secure website (hosted on this server in IIS) from a client browser I can clearly see that TLS 1.2 is used to secure the connection.

[image]

What to conclude ? Is **TLS 1.2** enabled ? Is there no need for the **TLS 1.2** key to be present in the registry ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-) TLS 1.2 is enabled by default on Windows Server 2012 and newer versions. This default behaviour means you don't need to create specific registry values to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to drill-down past "Protocols" and look at each individual version (ex: TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2, etc..) and check what the values are for Client and Server DWORDs (**DisabledByDefault** should be '0' and **Enabled** should be '1').

Comment: For recent implementations, the Protocols key is totally empty. There is nothing to drill down to.